# Leaflet set marker icon on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to change geojson marker icon on click following various exemple found on the web but I can't get it to work, it raise this error message:

```
TypeError: e.target.setIcon is not a function
```

Bellow the snippet

```
    var map = L.map('map',{ center: [44.1, 3.5], zoom: 10});
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: 'OpenStreetMap'}).addTo(map);

    var icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/256/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Azure.png',
        iconSize: [ 48, 48 ],
    });

    var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "test",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NUM": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 3.75, 44.25 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NUM": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 3.25, 44.0 ] ] } }
    ]}

    L.geoJson(data,{

      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          return L.marker(latlng);//, {icon: icon});
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.on('click', function (e){
            e.target.setIcon(icon);
          })
      }
    }).addTo(map);
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is originating from the GeoJSON. It does seem to be a valid GeoJSON because it plots on the map, but it must be tripping up Leaflet somehow. I think the fact that it's a MultiPoint feature is the cause.

Changing the GeoJSON to:

```
var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "test",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NUM": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3.75, 44.25 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NUM": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3.25, 44.0 ] } }
]}
```

makes it work. (Note: I just changed `"type"` from `MultiPoint` to `Point` and removed the double brackets, i.e. `[ [ 3.25, 44.0 ] ]` became`[ 3.25, 44.0 ]`.)

I'm not sure if it's possible to use MultiPoint geometry with the `onEachFeature` function, but it seems to be working with single point geometry.